# Best way to bulk create with foreign key

Tags: postgresql, foreign-key, bulk-insert

This might have been asked but I have not found a sufficient satisfactory answer yet.
Use case is that users can create a (temporary) network on a map via clicks and then press save to finish creating.

I want to bulk insert a network with nodes and edges into a Postgres DB. Two tables: nodes have name  and edges have a startnode_id and endnode_id and some other attributes. This means that both tables are almost always the same size.
What would be the fastest/most ideal solution to insert the nodes and edges without inserting them one by one (create two nodes and then an edge between them)?

- Is there a solution at all with Postgres?
- Is there an easy solution as in (example)

  ```sql
  INSERT INTO edges VALUES (name, createifnotexists(startnode), createifnotexists(endnode))
  ```
- Is it possible at all with temporary tables (given that foreign keys are needed)?
- If I create temporary tables, is a transaction necessary (or at least recommended)? (I'm using Prisma ORM)
- If this happens regularly is it better to use an existing table instead of creating a temporary one, that is emptied (truncated) at the end of the transaction?

Ideally the result would be a mapping of the old (temporary) IDs to the new (primary key) IDs so the client can update the IDs for future editing purposes.

Does anybody have experience with this problem and can give me some advice or does somebody have benchmarks on this issue?

---

First idea would be to create all nodes with `insert into values returning id` then go through the edges and basically create all the edges with current id and next id of the nodes, but alas! returning does guarantee the order of the returned ids.

Second idea would be to create an additional column with a temporary id. Fill the entries with 1 .. n and on return sort by this id to get the same order.

Comment: I think you are trying to optimize something that doesn't need optimizing. Just insert the values using `INSERT`.

Comment: The question is not about if I should INSERT the data into the database but how. Is there a different solution for the given problem than just inserting one after another but in a all at once way?

Comment: `INSERT` them one after the other. After all, you have foreign keys to maintain that should not be violated. As I said, you are trying to optimize something that does not need optimizing.

Comment: I guess that is up for interpretation. In my opinion this problem definitely needs optimization, and it would be possible to optimize if there was an option to guarantee the order in ``RETURNING``. I could then reduce the number of inserts to 2 (one for all the nodes and one for all the edges).

Comment: I am open to the possibility that my opinion could be wrong.